# To Boolean or not to Boolean?

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to model the highlight area of the attached model but each time I use to boolean tool set to difference, my edges in the render do not taper off as smooth as the original. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Hi :). This might be easier done manually without booleans. The corner geometry will be a lot cleaner.

Comment: This looks like normals problems, and the geometry might be correct. Are you using auto smooth?

Comment: @JachymMichal that's where I struggle when it come to the manual side of thing haha ... I started off manually but kept running into issues with the geometry. As a newbie I'm sure there's still some figuring out to do. How would you approach it?

Comment: @TheLabCat I didn't actually think of normals!!! I am using auto smooth though. Thanks for your prompt reply btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an example of a possible topology :)

To fill faces use *Vertex > New Face* (Shortcut: <kbd>F</kbd>)
And if you don't like n-gons, simply connect the vertices across as well.

[image]

Comment: I definitely wouldn't have thought of that approach! Thanks a bunch for the visual aid!!!

Comment: No problem, good luck with your project :)